# php show slave status

Tags: php, mysql

im not to sure why im getting a Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): when running this query

```
$query="SHOW SLAVE STATUS;";
$result = mysql_db_query("aid", $query, $con);
```

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using `mysql_db_query()` as opposed to `mysql_query()`?

Comment: Maybe it's a very recent (post-abolition) version of mySQL?

Comment: But seriously, you are not showing the actual warning, nor how you use `mysql_fetch_array()`. Also as @chigley already says, mysql_db_query is deprecated and its use discouraged

Answer (score 0):

well i use my_db_query because im new to php and thats all i really know well here is the full error

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/admin/domains/ismfast.com/public_html/V3/internal/karl_tools/slave_email.php on line 23

```
    $query="SHOW SLAVE STATUS;";


$result = mysql_db_query("aid", $query, $con); echo $result;
$r = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($r['Slave_SQL_Running']=="Yes"){echo $r['Exec_Master_Log_Pos']}
```

Comment: you can edit this info directly into your question. ... And try `echo mysql_error();` after sending the query, it should show why it fails

Comment: ok so it seems i dont have permission "Access denied for user 'repl'@'%' to database 'aid'" the repl user has REPLICATION CLIENT

Comment: and also REPLICATION slave permissions

Comment: 4 spaces before a line formats as code. To do this select a block an type `ctr-k`